# There is a hard-to-resolve issue when using pathinfo in apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, pathinfo

I deployed httpd（2.4）+php5.6（FastCGI mode）+mysql playform in centos.

I installed thinkphp, but there were some mistakes of pathinfo.

My configurations are as follows:

1.The configuration in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so remove comment
```

2.The configuration in httpd-vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www"
ServerName 192.168.79.130
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/$1
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options none
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

3.The configuration in web directory:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

4.The configuration in config.php:

```
'URL_MODEL'=>2
```

5.restart apache
"http://localhost/index.php/Index/test" in address bar,

You don't have permission to access /index.php/Index/test on this server.

It will display properly after entering "http://localhost/index.php?s=Index/test" in address bar.

So how can make it display properly after entering "http://localhost/index.php/Index/test"